# why some time javascript work on mozilla but not IE

Tags: javascript, flash

I have question why sometime javascript work properly on `mozilla` but in case of `Internet Explore` it not work.What the issues here
Is there any that I need to add in my javascript
Please reply if any body know.I have created a very small javascript but it nis not working on IE.

**code**

```
       <script language="javascript"> 
           function toggle(divid) {
                //alert(divid);
                 var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
                 var text = document.getElementById(divid);
                 var innerhtml= document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML;
                 //alert(innerhtml);
          if(ele.style.display == "block") 
             {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML;
        }
           else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML;
           }
                          } 
         </script>
          <div id="container"><embed height="450" width="450" wmode="transparent"  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/sIFYPQjYhv8&amp;rel=0&amp;color1=0x2b405b&amp;color2=0x6b8ab6&amp;border=1"></div>
   <?php for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++)
            { 
  ?>
        <div id="displayText<?php echo $i; ?>" onClick="javascript:toggle(this.id);"><embed height="150" width="150" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/sIFYPQjYhv8&amp;rel=0&amp;color1=0x2b405b&amp;color2=0x6b8ab6&amp;border=1"></div>
      <div id="toggleText" style="display: none">change inner html</div>
       <?php } ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Without the code, we can't help much.

Comment: I have added code have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Well, because different browsers have different levels of compliance to Javascript specifications.

See http://sputnik.googlelabs.com/

Comment: Actually, aswers the question in its current form.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely you have errors in your java script syntax. Next time in ie push F12 then select the script tab and click start debugging. You page will refresh and it should break on your error(s)

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons why some script works on one browser but not on another. For example you could have errors in your script and FireFox might be more permissive to errors than IE. Also you might have used some specific features not implemented by IE and which work fine in FireFox.

Comment: But it comes from admin mean I am using a wp you tube plugin

Answer (score 0):

This doens't work, because **embed** tag doesn't work in IE. This browser use different tag.
 Read [this article](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html) in order to know, how make flash movie working in different browsers. Even though, ancient IE3 and Netscape navigator browsers are described there, article is still correct for modern browsers and usefull.